# Add VPN To WIndows VPS via RDP ? (Internet access - A Quick n Easy Way)

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, vps, openvpn

I have a VPS running Windows Server 2008 R2 with one NIC hosting some websites.
I have tried to install OpenVPN with no success.

I am trying to set up for VPN with 1x user and password specifically to access internet services that are geo ip blocked when I am travelling abroad.

**The Network and Sharing Center console shows the following info for the second network interface:**

```
RAS (Dial In) Interface
Private Network

Access type: No Internet access
Connections:  [empty]
```

---

My laptop connects to the VPN successfully but there's no internet access through the VPN.

**The OpenVPN documentation** leaves me no clues as to what I've missed or require to get Internet Access through the software,

**Question:** so Im asking the Stack community if there is an easy walkthrough on getting VPN working on a VPS with one NIC, or a walkthrough in the case of having two NICs as I can always add another if that makes it much easier **?**

Thanks in advance for any/all feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found based on:

1) Ease of installation on the Server & Client

2) Lots of functionality

3) Good instructions

Is http://www.softether.org/ which is an open source solution with lots of security measures and control.

This VPS solution allowed HTTP Tunneling too - very easy to implement.